# Best way to drive high speed ADC with differential inputs

Tags: amplifier, adc, differential, sampling

Currently I am using AD8137 to convert my single ended signal to a differential signal. The ADC I am using is ADC3422 from TI and the data sheet suggests a passive circuit to drive low frequency inputs. I was wondering how do I know if the AD8137 component will be able to drive the ADC inputs at the 25 MSPS sampling rate. (Data Sheets below).

AD8137: https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8137.pdf

ADC3422: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/adc3422.pdf?ts=1659464004740&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FADC3422

Comment: What do you call "low frequency" inputs? Fig 184 says that 10 MHz is "low frequency" ...

Comment: I'm specifically referring to Fig. 183. My question is more geared towards using the AD8137 to drive the inputs at the 25 MSPS sampling rate.